# How does the Ubuntu team do automated testing?

Tags: canonical, quality

How does the Ubuntu team assures that bugs won't appear again?

I have seen it several times. A package is unusable after installing.

Yes, sometimes the bugs get fixed very fast.

But I see no effort to improve the automated testing, so that the bug won't appear again.

Here are two examples which affected me during the last two weeks:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1219857
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847

There are more examples, but listing them is not part of the question.

One comment from the `vsftp` bug page:

> Please help us by testing this new package. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed for documentation how to enable and use -proposed. Your feedback will aid us getting this update out to other Ubuntu users.

OK, but "testing" in the above quote is **manual** testing.

To ensure quality **automated** testing is needed.

For me manual testing is a waste of time. On the other hand, building automated tests does ensure quality.

Here again the question:

How does the Ubuntu team assures that bugs don't appear again?

**History of this question**

First the title was "How does the Ubuntu team do assure that bugs don't appear again?". Now it is "How does the Ubuntu team do automated testing?".
This was done because I believe that manual testing is not a solution. Please don't down-vote answers which only explain the way manual testing is done.

Comment: If testing, manual and automated, is not the answer, I am not sure what is.

Comment: @mikewhatever where did I say that automated testing is not the answer? I am not a native speaker, I guess there is a mistake in one if my sentences. Please tell where it is. For me automated testing is the answer.

Comment: Well, you start by asking: "How does the Ubuntu team assure that bugs don't appear again?". Then, you mention manual and automated testing, and then, ask the same question again, as if manual and automated testing was not the answer. If it is the answer, what else do you want to know? Also, if "For me automated testing is the answer", then why ask?

Comment: @mikewhatever you can look at this as two dimensions: "what is done" vs "what should be done". And "my thoughts" vs "ubuntu team thoughts". The matrix has 2x2=4 cells. This question is about "what is done be by the ubuntu team".  The question "what do I think should be done" is a different one.

Comment: I don't understand if this is an actual question or a rhetorical question; do you want to know the answer or are you making a point about the Ubuntu team not doing enough automatic testing?

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25376/open-source-linux-distribution-with-lts

Comment: @kos Up to now no one explained how ubuntu uses automated testing. This mean I don't talk about "not doing enough automatic testing". I want to know "is any automated testing done".

Comment: @guettli so why is that not your question title?

Comment: Actually you do talk about "not doing enough automatic testing": "I see no effort to improve the automated testing". Beside this, here's the problem with your question in my opinion: " I see no effort to improve the automated testing, so that the bug won't appear again" followed by "For me manual testing is a waste of time. On the other hand, building automated tests does ensure quality" and expecially the final "How does the Ubuntu team assures that bugs don't appear again?" after the first two make it look rhetorical.

Comment: if your question is about whether automated testing are performed or not and how I suggest you to rephrase it so that this is more clear. I believe the missunderstanding might just be due to a not excellent wording, but as it stands now it really *looks* more like a complain.

Comment: @kos thank you for your feedback. I changed the title to "How does the Ubuntu team do automated testing?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu does have automated testing. For example, automated testing is used to prevent your first bug example happening again. I was the one who fixed the first vsftpd bug you mentioned, and while doing so I also added an automated test to prevent the same thing from happening again. You can see this in the changelog entry that was posted to the bug itself:

```
vsftpd (3.0.2-1ubuntu2.14.04.1) trusty; urgency=medium

  * d/p/ubuntu-seccomp-gettimeofday.patch: permit gettimeofday() for logging
    calls (LP: #1219857).
  * Add dep8 smoke test.
 -- Robie Basak <robie.basak@ubuntu.com> Tue, 29 Apr 2014 15:33:07 +0000
```

I don't know why you consider the bug an example of a lack of automated testing, as I make multiple mentions of this in the bug. For example I said "dep8 test added to detect this in the future" and "The included dep8 test automatically verifies the fix for this bug" in the summary.

Remember that Ubuntu is a distribution: it is an integrated aggregration of many external projects that we call upstreams. Ubuntu wouldn't be possible without the work of others in the wider Free Software ecosystem, and likewise we are often dependent on the upstream authors to provide tests since they are the experts in their software.

Further, as we are an aggregation of different projects, a single automatic testing infrastructure doesn't make sense. Different areas have different needs. So our testing strategy is quite widespread to match these needs, covering both manual and automated testing through a number of different infrastructures.

Where upstream projects provide automated tests, we run them as part of the package build. The package build fails if the tests do not pass. Making sure that any available automated testing is enabled in this fashion is part of our [requirements for main inclusion](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuMainInclusionRequirements): *If the package ships a test suite, and there is no obvious reason why it cannot work during build (e. g. it needs root privileges or network access), it should be run during package build, and a failing test suite should fail the build.*

Additionally we run "automatic as-installed package testing" based on a specification called [dep8](http://dep.debian.net/deps/dep8/), which is designed for testing that the integration between packages work correctly. Package updates that regress dep8 tests do not go through to the development release until they are fixed.

I am less familiar with the automated testing done by the desktop and phone teams, but I know that more mechanisms exist because I have seen references to them over the years, and this includes automated GUI testing which I think is quite impressive. I welcome another answer that covers automated desktop and phone testing.

Comment: The link to dep8 displays this text "2012-06-25 ... In the working. In the meantime you can check ..." (three years old and still  in the working).  I feel sad, because this very important part (automated testing) gets so only little love.

Comment: The specification itself is still subject to change, but the system is live in Debian and Ubuntu and regularly worked on.  That is how we arrive at a well-designed specification that works for everyone: by actually using it. https://packages.qa.debian.org/a/autopkgtest.html shows you recent updates to the test runner for example. It gets plenty of love. Just because you don't understand how to interpret what you see doesn't make it any different. How about taking a more optimistic view and not jumping to inaccurate assumptions without asking questions to learn more first?

Comment: I asked here, and got no result for several days. The information about this workflow does not seem to be wide spread. I read between your lines that I did something wrong or stupid.  What was my mistake?

Comment: You seem to keep jumping to unfair and negative conclusions (which repeatedly turn out to be wrong). You did so in your original question and also in your comment here. Just because you saw an old date and spec draft status, you assumed that the spec is not getting any love. But it is as I pointed out. I think your mistake is that you keep viewing things with negativity glasses (eg. "I feel sad...") and communicating this negativity. You are asking good questions, but you seem to draw conclusions before you ask them rather than after you have the answers.

Comment: It took 16 days until the first answer revealed that automated testing gets done. This is a fact and  on its own neither negative nor positive. The judgement happens inside the reader. Each reader judges different. My way to react is to feel sad, that it needed 16 days until the beauty of automated testing which gets done was revealed.

Answer (score 5):

A number of ways.

1. Many eyes.

   Ubuntu is Open Source, meaning anyone can look at the code and see what the issue is. People who are interested in looking at the code will often find bugs in it, or as they use it, and [report them on launchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and [the public can even fix them](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/fixing-a-bug.html).

   [image]

   When you have tested it and suggested the fix you request a merge with the main Ubuntu package. Other developers review this change and if approved will add it in.

   Because anyone can fix them they are spotted quickly, and they are reviewed, they're less likely to hang around for a while. This leads onto the next point.

   These eyes also include computer eyes:

   > The upstream QA process must be documented/demonstrated and linked from the SRU tracking bug. In other cases where such upstream automatic testing is not available...

   Which shows that normally automatic testing is in place.
2. Beta Releases

   Before Ubuntu is released to the public, there are beta versions. Currently is the 15.10 Beta, to be [released on the 22nd of October 2015](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseSchedule). Lots, and lots of people will have been using, reviewing and bug fixing this before it is release (for [5 months 22 days](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=30&m1=04&y1=2015&d2=22&m2=10&y2=2015) in this case).

   This means that any bugs are removed promptly (because of the Many Eyes), and typical users are unaffected because it's fixed before it's officially released.
3. Expert code writers

   People who are good at writing high quality code are the people who are writing the code. There isn't just one person sitting writing Ubuntu like this:

   [image]

   There are people from all around the world, and people employed by Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu. All these people contribute a little bit of new code. If I write 2000 lines of code, there will be a lot of bugs. If 200 people write just 10, there will be a lot less.
4. Stable Foundations

   As far as I know, Ubuntu is not rewritten from the ground up each time there is a new release. Instead, the next version starts of as the current version (i.e. on 2015/04/30 both 15.10 and 15.04 were the same) and new features are added from there.

   If you have a good base to work from, then you have less code to write, and can trust what already exists. If you can rely on what's there, less bugs will get in.
5. Versioning and recording software

   If the same bug comes up more than once (in different versions, or the fix didn't work, or the bug came back due to another patch) then they have the documentation to explain how it was fixed - and they can fix it again.

---

As far as I can tell, there are no automated tests. But what is an automated test? If it compiles, is that one? You can't just say "automated tests" without explaining what it is

Comment: all your points (1..5) don't mention automated tests. I just can't believe that there is really no automated testing.

Comment: @guettli why are you so stuck on that. My answer doesn't mention it because I can't find evidence for any. Why is that so strange? And what is an automated test? If it compiles, is that an automated test? What are you expecting them to do?

Comment: @Tim maybe he does not know _Allan Turing_: _one machine cannot analyse another machine_ (or something close to that)

Comment: That programmer really needs to sit up straight - I think he needs glasses too...

Answer (score -2):

Dont write code with bugs. lol ok. I lost the will to write a detailed responce to this. Here's a decent article:
https://www.iiitd.edu.in/~jalote/papers/CommonBugs.pdf

and here is a good book about making [mistakes in C++](https://www.nostarch.com/hownotc.htm)

The best answer might be to just undertake some software development tasks, and see, for yourself where the problems come from. Handling unexpected input/ results is a pretty huge issue in my experience. Then there is down stream bugs. Like someone finds a vulnerability in iostream.h and every peice of software that calls that library then might also have that bug, need at least to be reviewed.

as for automated testing, it does exist, but it also has limitations. I'm not aware of a single solution that works on every language. If you're really interested, write us a genetic code debugger with some AI. As far as I know, all of it is still in its infancy, Heres some work from PhD students:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~clegoues/docs/legoues-icse09.pdf

Comment: It is very easy to write code which does not contain bugs: don't write any code. Result: no bugs. As soon as you write more than twenty lines there will be bugs. State of the art is test driven development with automated unit and integration tests: Red, green, refactor. I am missing how ubuntu does apply automated tests. And if you lost the will to write a response: don't do it. Why should you, if you don't want to? My hint: don't love the details (iostream.h) look at the whole picture :-)

Comment: I always thought the limit was seven lines of code?

Comment: @guettli You seem to have asked a question then wherever someone answers have become argumentative. Beyond that you have added a bounty (maybe to prevent closure) and have also been putting ubuntu down in the comments.

Comment: @Tim I don't understand what you try to tell me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @guettli What have you done wrong? The question is badly phrased and each answer you have refuted or been sarcastic in the comments. The question has -6 at the moment and the only reason it isn't closed is because it's got a bounty. You seem to be wanting an answer to tell you what you want to here - but maybe what you want to hear is not an answer?